# read integer from character array

Tags: c

I have a string, whith five integers, separated by spaces. For example: `12 33 45 0 1`

I have five variables, where I would like to load these numbers. Is it possible to call `atoi` more times? Or how is it even possible?

```
char c[] = "12 33 45 0 1";
int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
```

Comment: You probably need to learn one other concept called *array*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [strtok](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) to split the string into tokens, and use `atoi` on each one of them.

A simple example:

```
    char c[] = "1 2 3";         /* our input */
    char delim[] = " ";         /* the delimiters array */
    char *s1,*s2,*s3;           /* temporary strings */
    int a1, a2, a3;             /* output */

    s1=strtok(c,delim);         /* first call to strtok - pass the original string */
    a1=atoi(s1);                /* atoi - converts a string to an int */

    s2=strtok(NULL,delim);      /* for the next calls, pass NULL instead */
    a2=atoi(s2);

    s3=strtok(NULL,delim);
    a3=atoi(s3);
```

The tricky thing about `strtok` is that we pass the original string for the first token, and `NULL` for the other tokens.

Comment: Would you dare to put here sample piece of code doing it? Otherwise your answer seems too short and would fit better into comment rather then as complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sscanf` to convert the numbers, but be sure to check the return value

```
if ( sscanf( c, "%d%d%d%d%d", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4, &a5 ) != 5 )
    printf( "Well, that didn't work\n" );
```